# What might cause the Kubernetes API server to fail to write the client CA configmap?

Tags: go, certificate, kubernetes, certificate-authority

I'm experiencing that the Kubernetes API server fails to start during cluster bootstrapping with the following error log, apparently due to being unable to initialize its "client CA configmap":

```
E1029 14:35:56.211083       5 client_ca_hook.go:78] Timeout: request did not complete within allowed duration
F1029 14:35:56.211121       5 hooks.go:126] PostStartHook “ca-registration” failed: unable to initialize client CA configmap: timed out waiting for the condition
```

It seems to happen [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/17baaacb29247dbb6b04471f4bee831b0d617dc8/pkg/master/client_ca_hook.go#L67) in the Kubernetes source code. What might cause this error?

See the full log [here](https://slack-files.com/T09NY5SBT-F7SNQ2370-1671ad4b77).

**Update:** It seems that my etcd cluster isn't accessible from master nodes, even though the same command works from etcd member machines:

```
$ sudo ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --cacert=/opt/tectonic/tls/etcd-client-ca.crt \
--cert=/opt/tectonic/tls/etcd-client.crt --key=/opt/tectonic/tls/etcd-client.key \
--endpoints=https://coreos-testing-etcd-0.socialfoodie.club:2379 \
endpoint health
https://coreos-testing-etcd-0.socialfoodie.club:2379 is unhealthy: failed to connect: grpc: timed out when dialing
Error:  unhealthy cluster
```

Comment: Need to fix your log link.

Comment: @johnharris85 Ugh thanks!

Comment: Network connectivity to etcd? What's your cluster arch look like?

Comment: Thanks for taking an interest in this @johnharris85! I was wondering whether the apiserver can connect to etcd myself. Do you know how to test the connectivity from the apiserver (master) node to the etcd cluster? Regarding cluster arch, I'm using my port of Tectonic Installer to DigitalOcean: https://github.com/aknuds1/tectonic-installer/tree/digitalocean.

Let me know if you need more info from my side!

Comment: @johnharris85 I found out from testing that I can indeed not access etcd from my master node, even though it works from one of the etcd member machines. I added info on this to my question.

Comment: @johnharris85 I think I found the cause. The master node has an outdated version of the etcd CA, due to a synchronization issue in my Terraform setup. Working to resolve that one now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that despite the cryptic error message in the API server, the cause is that it can't write to the etcd cluster. The reason was that the API server was configured with a different client certificate authority than what the etcd cluster was using, due to a timing issue wrt. copying certificates in my Terraform cluster setup. I figured out that the CA was the problem by using curl to contact the etcd cluster instead of etcdctl, as it gave a clear error message.

Thanks to @johnharris85 for suggesting etcd connectivity being an issue!